# How not to repeat Use 'Package\Library' on each file in PHP when using namespace

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces, laravel-4

I am currently importing [Former](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former/wiki/Getting-started) library on non-laravel project (Wordpress, to be specific).

In Laravel you can import the library in the `app/config/app.php` and set it to `provider` so we can directly use the Library without declaring 
`use Former\Facades\Facade` at the top of each file.

However on non-Laravel project I do have to call `use Former\Facades\Former;` on each file before using them. Is there any other alternative so the namespace is automatically loaded?

I was looking at global namespace but I don't think that's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Have an [AliasLoader](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php), You can use it:

```
$aliases = array(
    'AnAlias' => 'Former\\Facades\\Former'
 );

Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance( $aliases )->register();
```

Now you can use `AnAlias` instead of `Former\\Facades\\Former`. Note that `Former\Facades\Former` class also has to be autoloadable by composer or other autoloader.

But yes, you have to require `Illuminate\Foundation` in `composer.json`, or you can, which is I think it is just fine to, copy `AliasLoader.php` File and change the namespace.

Comment: Seems like what I'm looking for.  :)